# Azure B2C Issues and Questions

Tags: azure-active-directory

I've been working with the Azure B2C for a couple of days now and have a few issues and questions:

1. Url that it creates to redirect for login is formed incorrectly.  It contains a question mark twice - after the url, and again after the profile name.  This causes a 404 not found error every time you login, log out, etc.  For example, the URL it tries to redirect to for login looks like this:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/samlmanbc.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_1_firstdemoprofile?client_id=08fcblahblah.  You'll notice a second question mark after the profile name, and that's what breaks it.
2. If I fix that and try and log in, it doesn't recognize the username / password of my account that's a global admin. It DOES recognize the username / password of a new user I created locally in the directory.
3. In the OnRedirectToIdentityProvider method, when the request type is authentication, the AuthenticationResponseChallenge is null, which makes this call fail:
   OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = await mgr.GetConfigurationByPolicyAsync(CancellationToken.None,                       notification.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseChallenge.Properties.Dictionary[Startup.PolicyKey]);

I worked around this by using the static string SignInPolicyId for the second parameter.  That works fine when an account already exists, but if it doesn't then Azure fails at login and says an account doesn't exist for the user.  So what is the right value to use there, and/or how does one initialize it so it isn't null?

4. The type of a claim that was added to a profile is preceded with "extension_"; is that always going to be true or just for now?  For example, I added a property called "favoriteTeam", but the claim type for it is "extension_favoriteTeam".
5. When you use FaceBook as an identity provider, is there any way to pass along the Facebook access token claim (http://www.facebook.com/claims/AccessToken)?  This was useful when using ACS with Facebook because your app can then use that token to make additional calls to Facebook to get data from it.

Answer (score 8):

In relation to issue 1 - I updated my reference Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions to v1.0.2.206221351 and it started working. I made some updates to other references before this, so if the first one doesn't work, try updating more assemblies from nuget.

Comment: Ah, brilliant Clarky888, that fixed issue #1 - thanks!  :-)

Comment: Hey @StevePeschka - Glad you figured that out - if you upgrade your OWIN packages to 3.0.1 you should be fine (this also upgrades the protocol extensions pacakge)

Comment: @StevePeschka I'd like to close on #3 if you're still interested... How did you initiate the authentication request? In other words, what did you click that triggered the `RedirectToIdentityProvider` notification?

Comment: Hey dstrockis, I was just using the .NET MVC sample example for the B2C stuff.  It's basically broken out of the box right now because of #3.  So my Index method in the Home controller has the Authorize attribute, and that's how it starts the auth process.

Comment: Fixed it for me too! I was going crazy trying to figure that out

Answer (score 0):

2. This is as expected. A page that signs in "local account" users will not sign in your work or school account (in this case, the global admin user).
3. Always going to be true. We will be cleaning up the Admin UX to make this more clear.
4. This is on our roadmap. No ETA as yet.

Comment: Interesting...thanks...WRT #3, what is the right value (or way) then to get a login page that both an existing user and a new user can use?  Or do you guys propose always landing on an anonymous page and have two different links - one for "Sign Up" and one for "Sign In"?

Comment: Look out for a new feature in Oct that will help solve the exact problem that you have described here :)