# Azure AD B2C AuthenticationResponseChallenge

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I'm working on Azure AD B2C for the last few days, got a sample and made it running. 
The issue I am facing is exactly like [AAD B2C issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723019/azure-b2c-issues-and-questions) point #3, but I could get any valuable comment in this question that may solve my problem. Example is running fine with me but when I implemented it in my solution, after giving the AAD B2C Credentials I'am ending up with:

```
   private async Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        PolicyConfigurationManager mgr = notification.Options.ConfigurationManager as PolicyConfigurationManager;
        if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
        {
            OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = await mgr.GetConfigurationByPolicyAsync(CancellationToken.None, notification.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseRevoke.Properties.Dictionary[Startup.PolicyKey]);
            notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = config.EndSessionEndpoint;
        }
        else
        {
            OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = await mgr.GetConfigurationByPolicyAsync(CancellationToken.None, notification.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseChallenge.Properties.Dictionary[Startup.PolicyKey]);
            notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = config.AuthorizationEndpoint;
        }
    }
```

In the 'else' part, AuthenticationResponseChallenge is always null, which is throwing an error. Can anyone give me a detailed reply as what is causing this and how to resolve it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem...did you find a solution? The answer below suggests to check PolicyConfigurationManager.cs but what part of it and what to look for? I stepped thru it and it seems to work. The example form MS works for me as well but when pot to my project it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem because the actual PolicyKey wasnt initiated correctly, make sure that you have the "PolicyAuthHelpers" (provided by Microsoft as a fix as their current libraries are unable to handle B2C). Step the code into PolicyConfigurationManager.cs and you can probably find why it breaks. Also verify that you have the correct policies configured in web.config, for example:

```
<add key="ida:SignInPolicyId" value="B2C_1_signin" />
```

If that doesnt help you could of course just hardcode it:

```
 OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = await mgr.GetConfigurationByPolicyAsync(CancellationToken.None, notification.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseChallenge.Properties.Dictionary["b2cpolicy"]);
```